# WCF and error handling , best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I have a theoretical question. I have a WCF web service that need to talk with .NET clients and an iPhone application.

In the service I have many methods like:

```
User Login(string email,string password); etc..
```

If successful, I want the service to return me the User.  Otherwise, I want the service to throw me an custom exception such as `EmailNotFoundException` or `PasswordNotCorrectException`.

I have been told it's not the best way to do so, especially because iPhone clients will use this service.

Should I change all my methods to return some `WrapperEntity` that will contain `Object` and error string/Exception object?

This is important for me, because sometimes I need to know why the operation fails. If `Login` returns null I will know the operation failed but I won't know why.

Comment: you could use regular Try Catch exception or RaiseExceptions for the null ones you could wrap those around try catch if you are unsure and do not want to assume that Invoking calls / methods will always pass.. the rule of thumb is to wrap everything in a Try catch or try catch finally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use exceptions in a WCF service to regularly communicate with a consumer of your service.  Instead, look at creating a response object that contains everything you would need to know about the operation.

Something like:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccessful
    {
        get { return User != null; }
    }
}
```

and then your Login operation would look something like:

```
LoginResponse Login(string email, string password)
{ ... }
```

This way, if the operation fails, you can put a message in the response that explains why.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx is "true" WCF way of error handling, but probably not suitable in your case.
You could use cods of erros, or some kind of Error class instance as a field of response, which is null in case of success...